# Regex to match XML elements in a text file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I have a text file consist of conversion instruction templates. 
I need to parse this text file,

I need to match something like this:

```
(Source: <element>)
```

And get the "element".

Or this pattern:

```
(Source: <element attr="name" value=""/>)
```

And get "element attr="name"".

I am currently using this regex:

```
\(Source:\ ?\<(.*?)\>\)
```

Sorry for being a newbie. :)

Thanks for all your help.

```
-JRC
```

Comment: what's the problem with your regex? Is it not functioning as expected?

Comment: Yeap, It gets all the text inside <>, which is I don't want,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `Regex` for detect attibs by both `”` or `"` characters:

```
\(Source:\s+<(\w+\s+(?:\w+=[\"”][^\"”]+[\"”])?)[^>]*>\)
```

and your code:

```
var result = Regex.Match(strInput, 
                         "\\(Source:\\s+<(\\w+\\s+(?:\\w+=[\"”][^\"”]+[\"”])?)[^>]*>")
                  .Groups[1].Value;
```

explain:

> ***`(subexpression)`***
>   Captures the matched subexpression and assigns it a zero-based ordinal number.
>
> ***`?`***
>   Matches the previous element zero or one time.
>
> ***`\w`***
>   Matches any word character.
>
> ***`+`***
>   Matches the previous element one or more times.

Comment: this is good, but it only gets the element name, if the element has an attribute I want to extract the 1st attribute also.

Comment: I updated my answer. just get group indexed 1

Comment: it only extract the element name :(( I am using Expresso to try the regex expression huhu

Comment: I tested my code in a .NET app! and I'm using [radsoftware RegexDesigner](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/?from=RegexDesigner)

Comment: for example you have a string = <lnv:PUB-ADDR-COUNTRY> (Source: <Property FormalName=”Country” Value=”” />).... I want to get this--> Property FormalName="Country", your regex only extract "Property"

Comment: Your sample contains `”` character and my regex detect attibs by `"` character.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks for that! Sorry for being a newbie! :)